# How to send an email using separate mailbox in Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a number of mailboxes set-up in Outlook, and I would like to use `Interop` to send an email, but not from the default Outlook account.

I have the following email boxes:

1. Main email mailbox (default)
2. support mailbox
3. info mailbox
4. accounts mailbox

How do I go about sending an email using the separate mailbox to send email?

The below code to send the email from the mail email box is as follows:

```
Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(oApp, smtpaddress);

oMsg.SendUsingAccount = account;
oRecip.Resolve();
//oMsg.Send();
(oMsg as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem).Send();

public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress)
{
        try
        {
            Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
            foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
            {
                // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
                if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress)
                {
                    return account;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToErrorFile("GetAccountForEmailAddress Method Error on: {0} " + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have got multiple accounts configured in the single mail profile you need to use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class which allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

But if you have separate profiles with Exchange accounts configured and want to send on behalf of another user consider using the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class.

Note, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.